# Keystone remove method executeQuery what to use instead?

Tags: keystonejs

Keystone remove method executeQuery what to use instead when I work with query?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `keystone.executeGraphQL` or when inside the access control or hooks you can do `context.executeGraphQL`